# Android ACRA Reporting

Tags: android, crash-reports, acra

I am trying to get basic reporting using ACRA in Android Studio in my test app (Lollipop).

So far, I have implemented following:

1. added dependancy in gradle

   ```
   compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
   ```
2. added MyApplication which extends Application and added ReportsCrashes annotation to it:

   ```
   @ReportsCrashes(

     resNotifTickerText = R.string.crash_notification_ticker_text,

     resNotifTitle = R.string.crash_notification_title,

     resNotifText = R.string.crash_notification_text,

     resNotifIcon = R.mipmap.error );

    public class MyApplication extends Application {

           private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();

            @Override
            public void onCreate(){
                super.onCreate();

                ACRA.init(this);
            }
        }
   ```

(BTW, sorry for code formatting above, but StackOverflow refused to format it properly for some reason)

This is based on ACRA documentation provided in github https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

3. added application name and INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest

   ```
   <!-- add INTERNET permission -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <!-- add application name -->
   <application
       android:name="MyApplication"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
4. My main activity has just one button, when clicked, it will crash app when it attempts to do division by zero

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private Button btnError;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnError = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnError);
            btnError.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_app_crash), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // this will crash your app throwing Arithmetic Exception
                            int number = 7 / 0;
                        }
                    };

                    Handler h = new Handler();
                    h.postDelayed(r, 2000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
   ```

I am expecting to see some kind of notification and some kind of report to get generated but I dont get any.  My app simply crashes at the spot where division by zero is attempted.

I am not sure what is that I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of notification you should select as

```
 mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
   //Available : Dialog,Notification,Toast and Silent
    resToastText = R.string.crash_text_toast
```

Here is the sample report parameter what i have used in my app.

```
    @ReportsCrashes(
    formUri="",
formUriBasicAuthLogin = "CloundantAuthLogin",
formUriBasicAuthPassword = "CloundantAuthKeyPassword",
    reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
    customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,ReportField.DEVICE_FEATURES,
    ReportField.USER_APP_START_DATE,ReportField.USER_CRASH_DATE,ReportField.TOTAL_MEM_SIZE,ReportField.USER_COMMENT,
        ReportField.THREAD_DETAILS, ReportField.STACK_TRACE }, 
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
    includeDropBoxSystemTags  = true,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
    resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
    resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
    resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
    resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. when defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
    resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
    )
```

Library used : acra-4.6.2

The best tutorial till date available here : http://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant

Comment: So, this will get the popup dialog and it allows me to enter the comment.  But where is it sent?  Where do I see it?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will get the dialog. It will be sent to wherever `formUri` points. In the code above that is nowhere. You should point it at your crash server.

Comment: @William would you mind recommending some good free crash servers I could use?  Thanks

Comment: @dbnex14 you can use IBM Cloudant server. It's easy to integrate with acra. Please refer the tutorial which is linked with answer .Check the updated answer

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar  and William  Thank you both, much appreciated